# How to merge two arrays with duplicate keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays $rate_row and $totalrowcost I am trying to update a row in the second array $totalrowcost based on the key in the first array $rate_row both arrays are always the same length.

I combine both arrays using the array_combine function

my code below works if there are no duplicate keys in the array but if i combine them when there are duplicate keys

I don't get the desired result.

Example:
If the key in $rate_row is 0 I need to set the value in $totalrowcost to 0 but when combining the array, one of the rows gets dropped and only one row with a key of 0 is preserved.

I've since learned since trying to figure this out that PHP will not allow an array to have a duplicate key, but i was wondering if there is some type of work around or hack that can help any ideas would be great thanks.

```
enter code here
  <?php 
  // Finds the lowest duty rate
    $lowest = 0; 
        $row_combine = array_combine($rate_row, $totalrowcost); 
          foreach($row_combine as $a => $combine_row):
             if ($a = 0){
                $lowest = $a;
             echo ""; 
        }
            endforeach; 


   // Finds the row value associated with the lowest duty rate          
          foreach($row_combine as $a => $combine_row):
               if ($a === $lowest){
            $lowest1 =  $combine_row; 
        }
            endforeach;     

         for($i = 0; $i < count($totalrowcost); $i++) {

enter code here

    if ($totalrowcost[$i] == $lowest1){
               $totalrowcost[$i] = 0;
        }
            }?>

enter code here
 $rate_row
 Array 
  ( 
    [0] => 35 
    [1] => 0 
    [2] => 40 
    [3] => 0 
    [4] => 45 
  )


$totalrowcost
Array ( 
    [0] => 100 
    [1] => 49.99 
    [2] => 102 
    [3] => 98 
    [4] => 125 
  )

$row_combine Output
Array ( 
    [35] => 100 
    [0] => 98 
    [40] => 102 
    [45] => 125 
  )


Desired $row_combine Output
Array ( 
   [35] => 100 
   [0] =>  49.99 
   [40] => 102 
   [0] => 98
   [45] => 125 
  )


Actual Output updated 
$totalrowcost
Array ( 
  [0] => 100 
  [1] => 49.99 
  [2] => 102 
  [3] => 0 
  [4] => 125 
  ) 

Desired Output updated 
$totalrowcost
Array ( 
  [0] => 100 
  [1] => 0 
  [2] => 102 
  [3] => 0 
  [4] => 125 
 )
```

Comment: You can't have two keys named 0 with different values. The best you can get is an multidimensional array with `arr[0][49.99, 98]`

Comment: can't you start this problem off with creating a `class` first with 2 properties `rate_row` and `totalrowcost`? it would be easier to work with that rather then having to deal with 2 arrays and having to keep it in sync or combine in your case

Comment: @Andrei I am bit of a newbie but if you point me in the direction of creating the class I will definitely give it a try. Thanks

Comment: can you explain 1 thing. `$row_rate` is suppose to apply some math to `$totalrowcost` because currently I can only see the 0 applying since the final result has any item mapped to `$row_rate` of 0 becomes zero, yet everything else stays the same....? wouldn't the final result be more like `3500, 0, 1996,0, 5625` I'm just confused as to what the rates are applying towards to to get the *actual* result

Comment: @Andrei Ok Thanks, I'll try to clarify the $row_rate and $totalrowcost are two separate arrays. I combine them so that I am able to loop through and find the lowest rate. Once finding the lowest rate I then loop through the $totalrowcost and change the value to 0 where the key is the lowest from $row_rate. but because i'm dropping one of the rows during the combine because of the duplicate key i am un abble to change it. so the $totalrowcost when summed later is not correct

Comment: @Igrooves so if we change `$rate_row` to `[35,5,40,5,45]` we expect the end result of `$totalrowcost` to be `[100,5,102,5,125]`

Comment: @Igrooves the edit to my answer will give you the correct answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for class to read up on the syntax and more information about them.

I'm a little unclear as to what problem you are trying to solve, perhaps an edit on what the use case is might help suggest other options.

**EDIT:**

```
  <?php
// you can use whatever input $rate_row is from user input or such along with the $totalrowcost
$rate_row = [35, 0, 40, 0, 45];
$totalrowcost = [100, 49.99, 102, 98, 125];

class Table {
  public $row_items;
  public $row_rates;
  public $row_rate_applied;    

  private $lowestRate;

  // used to init class values
  function __construct($items, $rates) {
    // set variables to class
    // might want to run validation here to make sure the count is = for $items and $rates
    $this->row_items = $items;
    $this->row_rates = $rates;
    $this->lowestRate = min($rates); // add validation to make sure rates is array http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

    // main guts that are used to solve your problem is inside this loop
    for($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
        // here we test if rates index == lowest. if it is set the item value to lowest
        if ($rates[$i] == $this->lowestRate) { 
            $this->row_rate_applied[$i] = $this->lowestRate;  
        } else {
            $this->row_rate_applied[$i] = $items[$i];
        }
    }
  }
 }

$table = new Table($totalrowcost, $rate_row);
echo var_dump($table->row_rate_applied);
```

The above code builds up and applies the rates against the items. I'm not 100% what the expected result is actually supposed to be because the code originally posted doesn't make a ton of sense for the **expected output**

essentially the idea is to build your Row

Comment: This did the trick. A million thank you's and also you now turned me on to learning how to use classes in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If the keys have no significant value (i.e. you just want to later loop over the final array) you can make sure the keys are unique before you merge them by appending a random name at the end of them.

Here is a function that merges two arrays while keeping the duplicate keys.

```
function array_uniqify_keys($array,$append='',$glue='--'){
    if($append === ''){
        $append = uniqid() . mt_rand(1000,9999);
    }
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        unset($array[$key]);
        $array[$key.$glue.$append] = $value;
    }
    return $array;
}
function array_merge_duplicate_safe($array1,$array2,$a1_name='',$a2_name=''){
    $array1 = array_uniqify_keys($array1,$a1_name);
    $array2 = array_uniqify_keys($array2,$a2_name);
    return array_merge($array1,$array2);
}
$array1 = [
    1 => 'foo',
    2 => 'boo'
];
$array2 = [
    1 => 'good',
    2 => 'bad',
    3 => 'ugly'
];
print_r(array_merge_duplicate_safe($array1,$array2));
```

The result for the above code is:

```
Array
(
    [1--59d393950489c8380] => foo
    [2--59d393950489c8380] => boo
    [1--59d39395049197021] => good
    [2--59d39395049197021] => bad
    [3--59d39395049197021] => ugly
)
```

You can also get the old key by `explode('--',$key)[0]`.